# Putting into a Map<String, ?>

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

So I have a Map that has some values in it being passed into a method:

```
public String doThis(Map<String, ?> context){
.....
}
```

And I'm trying to insert an addition attribute to this Map

```
String abc="123";
context.put("newAttr",abc);
```

But I am getting this error:

> The method put(String, capture#8-of ?) in the type Map is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

Is there anyway to perform this put without "cloning" the Map?

Comment: Are you trying to create a Map that can store any kind of object?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to put values of type X into a generic `Map` you need to declare the `Map` as `Map<String, ? super X>`. In your example X is `String`, so:

```
public String doThis(Map<String, ? super String> context){
.....
}
```

`Map<String, ? super X>` means: a map with keys of type `String` and values of a type which is X or a super-type of X. All such maps are ready to accept `String` instances as keys and X instances as values.

Comment: +1, but your last paragraph has a typo: you mean `super` rather than `extends`. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Remember PECS (Producer Extends, Consumer Super). You have a consumer (putting in), therefore it cannot be `extends`.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly we can **convert this map** into an easier to use form. Just with this simiple syntax: `(Map<String, ObjectOrSth>)unfriendlyMap`.

```
// Let's get this weird map.
HashMap<String, String> mapOrig = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, ?> mapQuestion = (Map<String, ?>)mapOrig;
//mapQuestion.put("key2", "?"); // impossible

// Convert it to almost anything...
Map<String, String> mapStr2 = (Map<String, String>)mapQuestion;
mapStr2.put("key2", "string2");
assertThat(mapOrig.get("key2")).isEqualTo("string2");
Map<String, Object> mapObj = (Map<String, Object>)mapQuestion;
mapObj.put("key3", "object");
assertThat(mapOrig.get("key3")).isEqualTo("object");
```